# How to display image on page using Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

> I am using thymeleaf ,html for front end development , when I try to
> set image on my page, image is not showing . How to set image ,images
> are in my local folder
> Here is my project structure
> [image]

> Here is the my code stuff ,that I used to set to display the image on
> page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Music</title>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/myMusic.css}">
</head>
<body>
   <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="brand"><img th:src="@{/static/images/logo.jpeg}"></li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

> this code  is not able to show the Image, Below out put of this code
> [image]

> I am using IntelIJ  ultimate 2021.1 as code editor

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot will serve everything in `src/main/resources/static` at the root, so you need to change:

```
<img th:src="@{/static/images/logo.jpeg}">
```

to:

```
<img th:src="@{/images/logo.jpeg}">
```